# How to search XML in PHP got by restful URL

Tags: php, xml, restful-url

I have got XML response from curl and trying to search some tag value but I am failing. Kindly somebody help me

Please bare as I am new to the PHP

```
<?php
$DynamicValue = 'KWI';
$url='https://www.example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Stations\')/items?$select=OfficeId&$filter='.urlencode("CityCode eq '" . $DynamicValue . "'");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$XML = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
foreach($XML->entry as $value)
{
    echo $value->OfficeId
}
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://www.example.com/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>a9f073a2-387e-4ac5-81b9-16b3ae81dba3</id><title /><updated>2017-03-20T08:15:47Z</updated><entry m:etag="&quot;61&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'5344b09b-d3f7-44ec-bd52-a8f5a99f23f9')/Items(23)</id><category term="SP.Data.StationsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5344b09b-d3f7-44ec-bd52-a8f5a99f23f9')/Items(23)" /><title /><updated>2017-03-20T08:15:47Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:OfficeId>KWIKU08AA</d:OfficeId></m:properties></content></entry></feed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work.

```
$string='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://www.example.com/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>a9f073a2-387e-4ac5-81b9-16b3ae81dba3</id><title /><updated>2017-03-20T08:15:47Z</updated><entry m:etag="&quot;61&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid\'5344b09b-d3f7-44ec-bd52-a8f5a99f23f9\')/Items(23)</id><category term="SP.Data.StationsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid\'5344b09b-d3f7-44ec-bd52-a8f5a99f23f9\')/Items(23)" /><title /><updated>2017-03-20T08:15:47Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:OfficeId>KWIKU08AA</d:OfficeId></m:properties></content></entry></feed>';
echo explode("</d:OfficeId>",explode("<d:OfficeId>", $string)[1])[0];
```

[PHP Code demo](https://eval.in/757438)

Comment: No, actually I want to search value of  <d:OfficeId>KWIKU08AA</d:OfficeId> How can I do that

Comment: @Milind now check